Why should one care about individual/minority rights ? And assuming tyranny of majority is a problem. How does one draw the balance?
There has been a lot of discussion over the years about where to draw the line between majority rights and minority/individual rights.
https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/democracy/#ProbPersMino

This account of the authority of democracy also provides some help with a vexing problem of democratic theory. This problem is the difficulty of persistent minorities. There is a persistent minority in a democratic society when that minority always loses in the voting. This is always a possibility in democracies because of the use of majority rule. If the society is divided into two or more highly unified voting blocks in which the members of each group votes in the same ways as all the other members of that group, then the group in the minority will find itself always on the losing end of the votes. This problem has plagued some societies, particularly those with indigenous peoples who live within developed societies. Though this problem is often connected with majority tyranny it is distinct from the problem of majority tyranny because it may be the case that the majority attempts to treat the minority well, in accordance with its conception of good treatment. It is just that the minority never agrees with the majority on what constitutes proper treatment. Being a persistent minority can be highly oppressive even if the majority does not try to act oppressively. This can be understood with the help of the very ideas that underpin democracy. Persons have interests in being able to correct for the cognitive biases of others and to be able to make the world in such a way that it makes sense to them. These interests are set back for a persistent minority since they never get their way.


The conception of democracy as grounded in public equality can shed light on this problem. It can say that the existence of a persistent minority violates public equality (Christiano 2008: chap. 7). In effect, a society in which there is a persistent minority is one in which that minority is being treated publicly as an inferior because it is clear that its fundamental interests are being set back. Hence to the extent that violations of public equality undercut the authority of a democratic assembly, the existence of a persistent minority undermines the authority of the democracy at least with respect to the minority. This suggests that certain institutions ought to be constructed so that the minority is not persistent.

One example of such debate.
Should we care about the interests of individuals and minorities ? How much should we care ? And how do we decide where to balance between rights of majority and the minority ?

Yes, there are Individual and group rights and if we agree that democracy is "majority rule", this does not mean that it can be "majority dictatorship". Every mature democracy needs a system of check and balance that must be adapted to circumstances. See e.g. Majority Rule, Minority Rights.

People mostly don't care until they end up in a minority. The current term for this appears to be 'privilege'.

One is always part of some minority group.
Maybe you belong to a minority religion. Maybe an ethnicity. Maybe you are vegan. Maybe your sexual orientation. Maybe you are a cyclist. Maybe you are a child. Maybe you are young, maybe you are old. Maybe you are a fan of a certain club. Maybe you are bald. Maybe you have red hair. Maybe you have an allergy. Maybe you are in a wheelchair.
Whatever you are or care about, the majority is not that or does not care about that.
So in the end, upholding the principle of protecting the rights of minorities you don't belong to, really protects your own rights.

We should try to do things that work for most everyone, bearing in mind that people essentially move from one minority to another throughout their lives.


'the minority is not persistent'..

Sounds kinda Final Solution orientated. Systems like proportional-representation allow minorities to hold power. I'd make the opposite case, a state that can't include & respect minorities, but forces homogenisation, is weak & oppressive. This passage is bad analysis, I can't help but think.
Intersubjectivity, is the basis for establishing rights, by taking the perspective: How would you see things in the circumstances of other people, if you had say different gender or ethnicity, but were otherwise yourself. By acting from that, we allow more people and groups to work together better, & the building of trust between them, & sharing of experiences in trusted ways.
You might like to see this answer: Studies exploring the rationale of gender equality

How does one define minority and majority in a democracy ? Does a minority  mean dissent in general ? I've always wondered how the UDHR was drafted for example. Did the drafters think of every possible relevant situation where the will of the majority can be in conflict with minorities or individuals

@ThrowawAccount: "During World War II, the Allies—known formally as the United Nations—adopted as their basic war aims the Four Freedoms: freedom of speech, freedom of religion, freedom from fear, and freedom from want." These were the guiding principles. After Nazi horrors were revealed a UN commission was set up to state the rights needed to sustain these more clearly, consisting of 18 members aiming to represent the globe, & they argued it out
